# How to set the default js engine in firefox SpiderMonkeywhile building?

Tags: firefox, build, spidermonkey

As we all know that there are several JSengines in firefox(like SpiderMonkey, traceMonkey, jaegerMonkey and so on), I am wondering whether we can set the default JSengine SpiderMonkey(which only usr interpreter mode) while we are building FF11.0 or 12.0 from source?

For example,are there any options we can set to make it?If so,which option can do?
Or if you know any other way, please tell me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just use preferences to turn off the JITs?  You can do that either after compiling or before compiling by editing the `modules/libpref/src/init/all.js` file.